# Is it possible to create an interface this general?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance

I'm going to be creating a lot of classes like

```
public static class M2SA
{
    // Median of 2 sorted arrays

    public static int Method ( int[] A, int[] B )
    {
        int m = A.Length, n = B.Length;
        if((m | n) == 0) 
            throw new ArgumentException("A and B cannot both be empty");
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = (m + n)/2; 
        while((i + j) < k)
        {
            if(i == m) ++j;
            else if(j == n || A[i] <= B[j]) ++i;
            else ++j;
        }
        if(i == m) return B[j];
        else if(j == n) return A[i];
        else return Math.Min(A[i],B[j]);
    }

    public static int Alternative ( int[] A, int[] B )
    {
        if ((A.Length | B.Length) == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("A and B cannot both be empty");
        int[] mergedAndSorted = A.Concat(B).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
        return mergedAndSorted[mergedAndSorted.Length / 2];
    }

    public static bool Test ()
    {
        return false;//Placeholder - haven't implemented yet
    }
}
```

in that they will all implement

- a `public static` method named `Method`
- a `public static` method named `Alternative` which has the same signature as `Method`
- a method `public static bool Test` that tests that whether `Method` and `Alternative` produce equivalent output for a given set of generated input.

The classes may have other methods that serve as helpers.

Is there a way I can create an interface general enough that it requires the above, but doesn't know anything beyond that? Or would it require that its methods have certain signatures?

For example, I might have another class like

```
public static class UnstablePartition
{

    public static void intswap(ref int a, ref int b)
    {
        // I'm amazed that there isn't already a method for this in the .NET library (???)
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }

    public delegate bool UnaryPredicate (int i);

    public static void Method ( int[] arr, UnaryPredicate pred )
    {
        for(int i = 0, j = arr.Length; i < j; )
        {
            if (!pred(arr[i])) ++i;
            else if (pred(arr[j])) --j;
            else intswap(ref arr[i],ref arr[j]);
        }
    }

    public static void Alternative(int[] arr, UnaryPredicate pred)
    {
        int[] partioned = new int[arr.Length];
        for (int ai = 0, pi = 0, pj = partioned.Length; ai < arr.Length; ++ai)
        {
            if (pred(arr[ai])) partioned[pj--] = arr[ai];
            else partioned[pi++] = arr[ai];
        }
        Array.Copy(partioned, arr, partioned.Length);
    }


    public static bool Test()
    {
        return false;//Placeholder - haven't implemented yet
    }

}
```

So I want an interface that is something like (I know the below is *completely* invalid ...)

```
public static interface InterviewQuestion
{
    public static Method;
    public static Alternative;
    public static bool Test();
}
```

and then I'll implement it like

```
public static class M2SA : InterviewQuestion
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a static interface with static members?... no.

Comment: Interfaces can't be `static` nor its members

Comment: What would be the point of a "static interface"? There's no static inheritance - if you're calling a static method, you are specifying exactly which class you mean. The way to solve this problem is to make your classes non-static.

Comment: Even if it was possible to define static methods in interfaces... what would be the point if they have different signatures? How is the compiler going to know which paramaters do those static methods expect?

Answer (score 4):

> [Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173156(v=vs.110).aspx) can contain methods, properties, events, indexers, or any combination of those four member types... An interface can't contain constants, fields, operators, instance constructors, destructors, or types. Interface members are automatically public, and they can't include any access modifiers. **Members also can't be static.**

It means that your interface would look like

```
public interface InterviewQuestion
{
    int Method(int[] a, int[] b);
    int Alternative(int[] a, int[] b);
    bool Test();
}
```

And your classes would look like

```
public class M2SA : InterviewQuestion
{
    public int Alternative(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        // implementation
    }

    public int Method(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        // implementation
    }

    public bool Test()
    {
        // implementation
    }
}

public class UnstablePartition : InterviewQuestion
{
    public int Alternative(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        // implementation
    }

    public int Method(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        // implementation
    }

    public bool Test()
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Or you can use [abstract class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173150.aspx). Then your implementation would look like

```
public abstract class InterviewQuestion
{
    public abstract int Method(int[] a, int[] b);
    public abstract int Alternative(int[] a, int[] b);
    public abstract bool Test();
}

public class M2SA : InterviewQuestion
{
    public override int Alternative(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        // implementation
    }

    public override int Method(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        // implementation
    }

    public override bool Test()
    {
        // implementation
    }
}

public class UnstablePartition : InterviewQuestion
{
    public override int Alternative(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        // implementation
    }

    public override int Method(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        // implementation
    }

    public override bool Test()
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: I agreed. Interfaces could not be static. So all you need is get rid of `static` keyword. It may confuse you since you may think that "`no state` why do I need to pass `this` pointer?" But In fact there is state and this state is pointers to class methods.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have commented on the fact that you're trying to make a static interface.

I think the deeper problem here is that you are trying to create an interface with inconsistent method signatures.

> Is there a way I can create an interface general enough that it requires the above, but doesn't know anything beyond that? Or would it require that its methods have certain signatures?

You're basically asking to create a partial interface with unknown method parameters. Interfaces must have a well defined signature.

What you could do is separate the parameters to a different interface or class, e.g.

```
public interface IInterviewQuestion
{
    int Method(IQuestionInput qParams);
    int Alternative(IQuestionInput qParams);
    bool Test();
}
```

Even so, the return types of the methods must be <s>constant</s> invariant.

Of course, `IQuestionInput` could probably contain anything, and how useful this is going to be depends on how you need to use the questions.

Comment: A generic interface would allow for the return types of the methods to not be an invariant anymore (being "constant" is in opposition to being "variable", both concepts referring to values, not to types -- what you intended with "constant" actually was "invariant").

Comment: @pid I don't think generics give much value here, since you can't eventually have a collection of mixed `T`'s to operate on, which I assume is the goal. re 'constant', fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this? :

```
public interface InterviewQuestion<T, TResult>
{
    TResult Method (Func<T, TResult> func);
    TResult Alternative (Func<T, TResult> func);
    bool Test ( );
}

public class M2SA : InterviewQuestion<Tuple<int[], int[]>, int>
{
    private static Lazy<M2SA> lazy = new Lazy<M2SA>(() => new M2SA(), true);

    public static M2SA Instance => lazy.Value;

    public int Alternative (Func<Tuple<int[], int[]>, int> func)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Method (Func<Tuple<int[], int[]>, int> func)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Test ( )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You still use regular interfaces and use a `Singleton` pattern to mimic static classes

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Monostate](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MonostatePattern) pattern to get around this. To quote from the website:

> A monostate is a "conceptual singleton" - all data members of a
>   monostate are static, so all instances of the monostate use the same
>   (static) data. Applications using a monostate can create any number of
>   instances that they desire, as each instance uses the same data. What
>   I find very nice about monostate classes is that they avoid all of the
>   complications about having to access a particular instance of a class.
>   Any instance is as good as another. I have found monostates do add
>   some confusion to those who are steeped in GOF Singletons, this may be
>   a bad thing.

Basically, instead of having a static class you make them a regular class. However, internally they behave as it they're static. Member variables are static so that they can be shared among instances of the class.

This approach allows you to implement the interfaces against the class. It also means you can dependency inject the classes via there interfaces if you want. Also, should you decide down the line that you'd like/need instance specific data it's easier to implement.

NOTE: In your case there's no state, so you'd be implementing the pattern to allow you to implement interfaces or abstract classes against your concrete types.

Comment: Does this relate directly to the question? The OP's classes are stateless -- it actually looks like they don't *need* to be static classes.

Comment: @TimBarrass - it doesn't really matter that they're stateless. They in effect singletons and he's looking to implement interfaces against them. The Monostate pattern allows for this, it's just in his case there's no state!

Comment: From your description, a monostate without any state is just a class -- am I missing something?

Comment: @TimBarrass - The difference is that it's not static. At the moment that don't have state, and I'm guessing that's why he's made them static. However, he's hit a language barrier which is he can't implement interfaces on them. This approach gets around that, even though the instances won't have state so will conceptually be static. If he does need to add state down the line he'll also be covered.

Comment: If they're static because they don't have state it's reasonable to assume that having state isn't going to be a requirement. Using a monostate (although interesting, I'd not seen it as a named pattern before) is then broadly irrelevant, as what's useful is just converting them to normal classes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have static interfaces. To make benefit of interfaces, you have to make it regular member methods.

You could have this interface:

```
public interface InterviewQuestion<T1, T2>
{
    public Method<T1 arg1, T2 arg2>();
    public Alternative<T1 arg1, T2 arg2>();
    public bool Test();
}
```

Then you implementations implementing it:

```
public class M2SA : InterviewQuestion<int[], int[]>
{
  //...
}
```

And a static access to it (or even more dynamic by access it by T1 for instance, a repository, whatever, this here is the most trivial static way):

```
public static class InterviewQuestions
{
  private static M2SA m2sa = new M2SA();
  public static M2SA M2SA => m2sa;

  // ...
}
```

Access:

```
InterviewQuestions.M2SA.Method(blah, blah);
```

This doesn't have much of a value until you start writing code which is not statically bound to one of the implementations. You could find the implementation by a search criteria like T1 or T2 or both or something else. You could create an interface without generic arguments and providing the methods with object arguments, which allows calling it without knowing the types. Etc.